# undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass in ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, nil, nil, nil]

c.map { |i| p i if i > 10 }

NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

How to avoid `nil` values during comparison?

Comment: what's the expected output?? what's `p`?

Comment: seems he/she wants to output integers > 10

Comment: @KarolyHorvath p() is a Kernel method that writes obj.inspect to the standard output.

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev: yes, of course... sry!!

Answer (score 3):

Try as below :

```
c.each { |i| p i if i.to_i > 10 } # fix is to use `to_i`
```

Use [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each) method instead of [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map), when you want to traverse the array, and outputs some elements when there is a match, as you are doing. If you use the method `to_i`, then whenever there is `nil` in your source array, then `nil.to_i` will convert it to `0`. And if it found any integers like `1`,`2` etc, then you will get back the same integers.

Look also [`NilClass#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i) and [`Fixnum#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Integer.html#method-i-to_i) methods.

Comment: Using each is correct suggestion here. I would say to use array.compact to avoid undefined method error for comparison operator when used for nil in place of using nil.to_i

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways.

1. Use [`Array.compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-compact):

   ```
   c.compact.each { |i| p i if i > 10 }
   ```

   The `Array#compact` method gives you a new array with all `nil`s removed.
2. Use `next`:

   ```
   c.each do |i|
     next if i.nil?
     p i if i > 10
   end
   ```

   This avoids creating a new array.

Note the use of `each` instead of `map`. The latter is used when you are creating a new array with the result of applying the block to each element in the original array, such as `c.map { |i| i + 1 }`, which is equivalent to `c.map &:succ`.

If all you need to do is iterate over the array and apply side effects such as printing numbers, `each` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, nil, nil, nil]

c.compact.each{|i| p i if i > 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c.each { |i| p i if !i.nil? && i > 10 }
```

Comment: `c.each { |i| p i if i && i > 10 }` may be preferable to the double-negative (Unlike `!i.nil?`, this precludes `false`, which may not be a bad thing, as `false` would raise an exception.)  `c.each { |i| p i unless i.nil? || i <= 10 }` is another way to express what you have.